# Why does this code wait 1000ms instead of 500ms?

Tags: java, multithreading, io, stream

I don't understand how this code prints 1000 instead of 500. Is there something I am missing?

```
    PipedOutputStream writer = new PipedOutputStream();
    PipedInputStream reader = new PipedInputStream();
    writer.connect(reader);
    BufferedReader stream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(reader));

    ScheduledExecutorService thread = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor(new ThreadFactoryBuilder().build());
    thread.schedule(() -> {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
            writer.write("test\n".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        } catch (InterruptedException | IOException ignored) {
        }
    }, 0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    stream.readLine();
    long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
    System.out.println(duration);
```

Comment: Assuming that `PipedOutputStream` is a subclass of `OutputStream`, in the given code it is never flushed, which might happen implicitly at the second time the task is scheduled, causing a wait time of 1000 ms before the `BufferedReader` actually receives some input.

Comment: @Izruo That was it, flushing the writer fixed the problem. Although this isnt scheduleAtFixedRate just schedule so the task would not be run twice. Can you write this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I'm not sure why you expect the timing of `stream.readline()` to be 500 ms.  Are you expecting the `readLine()` to block for exactly as long as the scheduled thread takes to complete?  Assuming you flush after write, then the `duration` will be _at least_ but maybe more than 500ms.  I hope you aren't depending on `duration` to have some specific range of values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `PipedOutputStream` is a subclass of `OutputStream`, in the given code it is never flushed.

Since we don't know the exact caching or flushing behavior of `PipedOutputstream` it *may* happen that the bytes for `test\n` are not written to the connected `PipedInputStream` immediately after the wait process of 500 ms has completed. Instead it forwards the first chunk of data to its connected sink at some later point.

Again, assuming that `PipedOutputStream` is a subclass of `OutputStream`, flushing the stream will fix this behaviour.

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(500);
    writer.write("test\n".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    writer.flush();
} catch (InterruptedException | IOException ignored) {
}
```